# Can a pi powered by a POE hat use an external Storage?

Tags: storage, poe

I have a handful of POE security cameras. I want to add a raspberry pi with shinobi or some other NVR software. I have an extra POE port on my switch and would like to just use a POE hat to power the pi. That said, I do want to add some storage to put video on. I'm considering a USB to SATA adaptor with a solid state drive -- but nearly every single one of the reviews for something like that say "Use a good power supply!"

So -- is the [official POE hat](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/poe-hat/) a "good" power supply?

Comment: I have 3 x Pi4's using a cheaper third-party PoE hat. The Pi's all boot from SSD's using a (good) USB to SATA adapter (no SD cards in any of them) - never had a power issue

Comment: @JaromandaX Seems like a reasonable answer...  I notice the spec for the official hat says it should provide 2.5A @ 5V.

Comment: @goldilocks - not sure it is a reasonable answer since I'm not using the "official PoE hat" - I can't find the specs for the hat I'm using